# Logic flow of rectangle to N-rectangles collision detection

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, logic, collision-detection

I have a really hard time here figuring out the error in my program.

My code only works in `2` rectangles but if I increment number of rectangle, it doesn't work at all.

My program flows like this:

`pseudo code`

```
for (i = 0 to N_of_rectangles - 1)
{

    Rectangle& r1 = rect[i];

    if (r1.is_grab_by_mouse())
    {
        for (j = 0 to N_of_rectanges - 1)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                skip_this_loop    //skip for any self-checking
            }

            Rectangle& r2 = rect[j];

            if (not Rectangle.collide(r1, r2))
            {

                if (r1.restricken_move()) break;    //restricken move will be true if
                                                    //*this rect will collide to !*this
                if (r1.movement == HORIZONTAL)
                    r1.move_x_along_with_mouse()
                else    //VERTICAL
                    r1.move_y_along_with_mouse()
            }
            else
            {
                r1.resolve_collision()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did try all the algorithm for rectangle collision detection I searched in google and mine but it seems that I have a `logic flaw` here.

(PS. my rec-collision detection is not for rotated rectangles)

Comment: What does `r1.move()` do? For a rectangle with no collisions, it will be executed `N_of_rectangles-1` times per tick. Is that OK?

Comment: it does move for x or y only not both.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have 2 loops in there? 
Anyways I think that you should only move r1 if he does not collide at all, not everytime he does not collide with a rectangle.
The code should be like that :

```
boolean collision=false
   for (j to N_of_rectanges)
   {
      if (i == j)
      {
        skip_this_loop
      }

       if (Rectangle.collide(r1, r2))
      {
         r1.resolve_collision()
         collision=true
      }
    }
  if(not collision){
    r1.move()
  }
```

Comment: It has two loops because I want `*this` to check for all included rectangles not including `*this`. I don't think it would work for only 1 loop(?)

Comment: Can you clarify your purpose, for me the problem was the following :
You have N rectangles; you want to check if the rectangle grabbed by mouse has encountered any of the other rectangles. Your first loop is to know if a rectangle is grabbed by mouse? (if so, you may consider event-driven programming if possible) You may use array to clarify all this ( rectangles[i] and rectangles[j] ). 
I think you should also clarify the y and x movements you are talking about in your reply to Kevin(edit the question's body).

Comment: Ok so the solution I suggest seems more logical.
In your code, given 3 rectangles called 1,2,3 which are all 1x1 rectangles. Let's imagine we move the rectangle 1 from x=0 to x=5. On its way it will collide with the rectangle 3 at position x=1.
In your code, the first time we will check 1 against 1, same rectangle, we skip. Second iteration : 1 against 2 : no collision, the rectangle 1 moves to position x=1.Third iteration : 1 against 3 : no collision, the rectangle 1 moves to position x=2 whereas he should have collided.

Comment: I did try it but still no luck here. I removed the other loop.

Comment: I will give you the source code and check it for your self if you want? I really want this to be done asap cause it bothers me all the time.

Comment: In a non event-driven, real time programming the first loop is compulsory.If the solution given (trying to move the rectangle only when there was no collision at all)doesn't solve your issue, I'm not sure I could be of any help.

Comment: You may add some more informations : when/how do you call your first loop? What is the movement, is it one unit by one unit or a bigger movement? Are you sure your collide function is ok? You keep talking of a `this`, I am not sure of the meaning you have for it.You should change when possible to the r1 and r2 instead of `this`. If you can't change it to r1 or r2 somewhere, clarify it.

Comment: sorry for that but I mean by `*this` is the one that has been `grabbed by mouse`. I will try to improve my question later on.